# Sorting an array in lexicographical order. Pure bash

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have two arrays with IPs. I want to combine them into a third array and apply an ascending ordering.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

dbip[0]=1.1.1.1
dbip[1]=1.1.1.2
dbip[2]=1.1.1.3
dbip[3]=1.1.1.4
dbip[4]=1.1.1.5
dbip[5]=1.1.1.10
dbip[6]=1.1.1.9

ngip[0]=1.1.1.5
ngip[1]=1.1.1.6
ngip[2]=1.1.1.7
ngip[3]=1.1.1.1
ngip[4]=1.1.1.11


#I am adding the dbip array into the final one
for (( i=0; i<${#dbip[@]}; i++ ))
do
        allip[$i]=${dbip[$i]}
done

#Remembering the no. of elements in the final array
var=${#allip[@]}
echo "$var"

#Adding the ngip array into the final one
for (( i=0; i<${#ngip[@]}; i++ ))
do
        allip[$var+$i]=${ngip[$i]}
done

#Printing the initial order of the elements in the array
echo "size= ${#allip[@]}"

for (( i=0; i<${#allip[@]}; i++ ))
do
        echo "${allip[$i]}"
done

#Sorting the array in ascending order
for (( i=0; i<${#allip[@]}; i++ ))
do
        for (( j=$i; j<${#allip[@]}; j++ ))
        do
                if [ allip[$i] \> allip[$j] ];
                then
                        aux=${allip[$i]}
                        allip[$i]=${allip[$j]}
                        allip[$j]=$aux;
                fi
        done
done

echo "###############################"

#Printing the final form of the array
for (( i=0; i<${#allip[@]}; i++ ))
do
        echo "${allip[$i]}"
done
```

Problem is that the output is not ordered in numerical or lexicographical way.

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.11
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.9
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.6
```

The output should be like this:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
.......
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.11
```

or like this

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.11
```

so i can remove the duplicates later.

How can i do this in a pure programming way in bash. No pipes.

Note that IPs can be from different classes: 10.55.72.190, 10.55.70.1, 10.51.72.44, etc.

Comment: Is implementing Bubble Sort in Bash really better than using the "sort" program?

Comment: Yes, because i have 4 arrays. Two with IPS and two with Hostnames associated to the IPs. What i am doing to the IP arrays i need to do with Hostname arrays.

Comment: bash also supports [associative arrays](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays).

Comment: @Florin that makes your question very different and you should look to use associative arrays like anishane suggests.

Comment: @Florin, please update your question to reflect your *real* problem. "I need to sort a list of IPs without calling `sort`" isn't really your question, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is "pure" bash:

```
dbip=( [0]=1.1.1.1 [1]=1.1.1.2 [2]=1.1.1.3 [3]=1.1.1.4 [4]=1.1.1.5 [5]=1.1.1.10 [6]=1.1.1.9 )
ngip=( [0]=1.1.1.5 [1]=1.1.1.6 [2]=1.1.1.7 [3]=1.1.1.1 [4]=1.1.1.11 )
allip=( $(printf "%s\n" "${dbip[@]}" "${ngip[@]}" | sort -V) )
printf "%s\n" "${allip[@]}"
```

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.9
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.11
```

Comment: I was just about answer with `sort -V` luckily I spotted that's what you are using +1 *(I wouldn't call it pure `bash` however)*. Also worth noting `-V` requires `GNU sort`.

Comment: I would be a complete waste of time (pun intended) to implement a sorting algorithm in a shell language.

Comment: Completely agree! It looks like the OP didn't ask the right question for the problem they are trying to solve any way, see the comments.

Comment: I am asking the right question. All i need is the order in the array to be like glenn posted. Can it be done or not ?

Comment: I agree with the OP: Asking to do something (sort) in one language. Not calling another program or using another language. Would you answer 'use "fork/exec sort..."' if someone asked about implementing "sort" in C ?

Answer (score 0):

A pure bash implementation (no call to any tool like sort).

The idea: convert IPs to integers, perform a bubble sort on these, convert back to x.x.x.x format.

```
#! /bin/bash

ips=(192.0.2.235 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.11 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.3 1.1.1.4
     1.1.1.5 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.9 1.1.1.5 1.1.1.7 1.1.1.6)
# integer IPs
intips=()

echo Initial addresses:
for ((i=0; i<${#ips[@]}; ++i)); do
    echo ${ips[$i]}
done
echo

# convert ip to int
ip2int() {
    local -i intip
    local -a ip
    local IFS="."

    ip=($1)

    intip=$(( ${ip[0]}*2**24 + ${ip[1]}*2**16 + ${ip[2]}*2**8 + ${ip[3]} ))
    echo $intip
}

# convert int to ip
int2ip() {
    local -i a1 a2 a3 a4 intip=$1

    a1=$(( intip / (2**24) )); ((intip -= a1*2**24))
    a2=$(( intip / (2**16) )); ((intip -= a2*2**16))
    a3=$(( intip / (2**8) ));  ((intip -= a3*2**8))
    a4=$(($intip))
    echo "$a1.$a2.$a3.$a4"
}

# simple bubble sort (ascending) of an integer array
sortn_asc() {
    local -a array=( "$@" )
    local -i max i val1 val2

    for (( max=$(( ${#array[@]} - 1 )); max > 0; max-- )); do
        for (( i=0; i<max; i++ )); do
            val1=${array[$i]}
            val2=${array[$((i + 1))]}

            # switch if necessary
            if (( $val1 > $val2 )); then
                local tmp=$val1
                array[$i]=$val2
                array[$(($i + 1))]=$tmp
            fi
        done
    done
    echo "${array[@]}"
}

# convert ips to integers
for ((i=0; i<${#ips[@]}; ++i)); do
    intips[$i]=$(ip2int ${ips[$i]})
done

# sort
intips=( $(sortn_asc ${intips[@]}) )

# convert and echo sorted integers table
echo Sorted addresses:
for ((i=0; i<${#intips[@]}; ++i)); do
    echo $(int2ip ${intips[$i]})
done

exit 0
```

The output:

```
br@lorien:~/tmp$ ./19398658.sh 
Initial addresses:
192.0.2.235
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.11
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.9
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.6

Sorted addresses:
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.9
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.11
192.0.2.235
```